# Can i run my code of API level 7 i.e eclair in android studio?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-version, android-applicationinfo, android-min-sdk

I want to make changes in my old version code that is in API level 7 I need to add navigation sliding bar like google play store has and add FAB button in it
My question is

> Q-1) If I add this FAB to my old code will my app crash?
>
> Q-2) Is there any way to make my old version code to run on other version
> of android i.e highest version of android?

Comment: ya i will try bt i dont want my app to crash after all work

Answer (score 0):

I have run my code for API level 8 in android studio, And I still Use to develop a legacy project on API level 8 and above. By theoretically API 7 should support, Try it. or you can set the compile level of your app as API 8 keeping the lowest version allowed to 7 and it should work.

Comment: i had already run my old version code in android studio, but it shows the gradle error and its not only that i need to add FAB and navigation bar in that code which is supported in higher level of android i.e. API level 21 or more than that .... so can i do those changes to my old version code?

Comment: I am not getting error now i just updated and intsalled the low level API in SDK manager and edited the manifest file  with  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion=7" />   to   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="21" /> it just show warning now...

Comment: error i get is my some .xml files dont get open in AVD or in design phase

Comment: @Shashi kant Singh

Do you have maybe an example project for your API Level 8? like an Android Studio Hello World maybe?

I am developing an app for an embedded infotaiment system that has Android 2.2

Because the lowest api I can go if I create a new project in Android Studio 2021 is API Level 16